# How can I change the default timeout used by the waitForObject function in Squish

Tags: python, qt, automated-tests, squish

Function used for waitForObject is below. I want everytime this function it used it waits for default amount of seconds.

```
def login():
    type(waitForObject(names.login_lineEditUserId_QLineEdit), "786")
```

Answer (score 7):

The default timeout for waitForObject() is testSettings.waitForObjectTimeout.
It can be changed in settings.xml, or in your test script, or from
the Test Settings - AUT tab (Squish 6.4 only).

https://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/rgs-squish.html#testSettings.waitForObjectTimeout-property

With best Regards,

Alan Ezust

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the timeout depends on the line of your code, modify the call by adding the timeout in milliseconds as last argument of the *WaitForObject* function.

For example, for a timeout of 4 seconds, change your code from :

```
type(waitForObject(names.login_lineEditUserId_QLineEdit), "786")
```

to :

```
type(waitForObject(names.login_lineEditUserId_QLineEdit, 4000), "786")
```

It works the same way for *WaitForObjectItem* and *WaitForObjectExists*.

Note : The default value for the timeout is 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I made all necessary changes in `settings.xml`, and all other AUT settings (nothing worked for me apart from physically throwing a snooze function in between).

Currently I just use `time.sleep(40)`, since 40 is a magic number, you can just declare them in a global file and call it every time you want to use those objects.

Just to be clear:

1. `Time.sleep(30)` // this way the system waits for 30 seconds before executing line 2
2. `type(waitForObject(names.login_lineEditUserId_QLineEdit), "786")`
   // Avoid using co-ordinates because if objects or window move those position then your test would fail, by mapping your object, squish will just find those objects with a specific id)

Don't forget to add `import time` at the beginning of your program.